# RGBDSLAM sum of covariances not invertible

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to use RGBDSLAM on bag file data. After start of processing there is a lot of errors in terminal like this:

```
[ERROR] [1329932176.311416364]: Sum of Covariances not invertible: 
 inf  inf -inf
 inf  inf -inf
-inf -inf  inf
[ERROR] [1329932176.311986136]: Sum of Covariances not invertible: 
 inf  inf -inf
 inf  inf -inf
-inf -inf  inf
```

What is wrong?

My launchfile: http://pastebin.com/n8nuKnXD

Info of used bag file:

```
path:        2012-02-17-12-09-16.bag
version:     2.0
duration:    6:00s (360s)
start:       Feb 17 2012 12:09:16.69 (1329476956.69)
end:         Feb 17 2012 12:15:16.73 (1329477316.73)
size:        18.1 GB
messages:    95096
compression: none [17979/17979 chunks]
types:       geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped [953b798c0f514ff060a53a3498ce6246]
             geometry_msgs/Twist                     [9f195f881246fdfa2798d1d3eebca84a]
             nav_msgs/Odometry                       [cd5e73d190d741a2f92e81eda573aca7]
             sensor_msgs/CameraInfo                  [c9a58c1b0b154e0e6da7578cb991d214]
             sensor_msgs/Image                       [060021388200f6f0f447d0fcd9c64743]
             tf/tfMessage                            [94810edda583a504dfda3829e70d7eec]
topics:      /camera/depth/camera_info    8991 msgs    : sensor_msgs/CameraInfo                 
             /camera/depth/image_raw      8991 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Image                      
             /camera/rgb/camera_info      9000 msgs    : sensor_msgs/CameraInfo                 
             /camera/rgb/image_color      9000 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Image                      
             /camera/rgb/image_mono       9000 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Image                      
             /camera/rgb/image_raw        9000 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Image                      
             /cmd_vel                     1530 msgs    : geometry_msgs/Twist                    
             /odom                        3601 msgs    : nav_msgs/Odometry                      
             /robot_pose_ekf/odom         3600 msgs    : geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped
             /tf                         32383 msgs    : tf/tfMessage                            (7 connections)
```

Thanks for any hints.

**UPDATE**

I've added this line to the code:

```
depth_float_img.convertTo(depth_float_img,CV_32FC1,0.001);
```

RGBDSlam is running for some time but then it crashes...

Logfile is here: http://mysharegadget.com/144891718

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28196/rgbdslam-sum-of-covariances-not-invertible/) by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 704 on 2012-02-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2012-02-22**:
And also log file: http://mysharegadget.com/571660235

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

RGBDSLAM requires /camera/depth/image (which contains float values in meter), not /camera/depth/image_raw (which provides 16bit integer values in mm).
If you don't want to re-record the data and know C++, you can add a conversion in src/openni_listener.cpp in the method

```
void OpenNIListener::noCloudCallback (const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& visual_img_msg,...)
```

There are two lines:

```
cv::Mat depth_float_img = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(depth_img_msg)->image;
```

Add changes s.t. the image is converted to float and meter there.

Please try:

```
cv::Mat depth_float_img2;
depth_float_img.convertTo(depth_float_img2,CV_32FC1);
depth_float_img = depth_float_img2 * 0.001
```

This should avoid all problems with casting and inplace. Hope that helps with the crash. Otherwise try setting the debug-flag in the launchfile (line 9) and see where (and hopefully why) it crashes.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2012-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2012-02-28**:
Thanks for answer! I've added conversion to float and scaling to milimetres (see updated question). RGBDSlam is running for some time and then crash.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-02-28**:
Hm, I see no obvious problem. The NaN warnings in the log could be avoided if you also converted the (original) depth image with CV_8UC1 into the depth_mono8_img_ variable. However that shouldn't cause the crash.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-02-28**:
The lines saying "RANSAC found no valid trafo, but had initially X feature matches with average ratio Y" makes me think that something is wrong with the depth value, because X and Y are very good. Could be because you convert inplace or because of casting. See the update of my post